# Problem with my tkinter degres convertissor

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my problem: Normally if you execute my code, you can type a Fahrenheit or Celsius Degrees value, and you can have the opposite value (if you type a Celsius, you get a Fahrenheit). I really don't know why it is not working. Please if you know something that could help me, tell me. Thanks a lot.

Here is the code :

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Conversion")
window.geometry("720x480")
window.configure(bg="turquoise")

def choixUser(event):
    Conversion = EntréeConversion.get()
    if Conversion == "A":
        titreEntréeFarenheit = Label(window, text="Degrés Farenheit : ", font=("Segoe print", 15), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
        titreEntréeFarenheit.place(x=20, y=230)
        EntréeFarenheit = Entry(window, width=15)
        EntréeFarenheit.place(x=220, y=243)
        ValeurFarenheit = str(EntréeFarenheit.get())
        
        if len(ValeurFarenheit) > 0:
            ValeurFarenheit = EntréeFarenheit.get()
            ValeurFarenheit = int(ValeurFarenheit)
            FaC = (ValeurFarenheit - 32)/1.8000

            résultatText = (EntréeFarenheit, "devient", FaC, "°C")
            RésultatFaC = Label(window, text=résultatText, font=("Segoe print", 20), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
            RésultatFaC.place(x=200, y=300)

    if Conversion == "B":
        titreEntréeCelsius = Label(window, text="Degrés Celsius : ", font=("Segoe print", 15), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
        titreEntréeCelsius.place(x=20, y=230)
        EntréeCelsius = Entry(window, width=15)
        EntréeCelsius.place(x=185, y=243)
        ValeurCelsius = str(EntréeCelsius.get())

        if len(ValeurCelsius) > 0:
            ValeurCelsius = EntréeCelsius.get()
            ValeurCelsius = int(ValeurCelsius)
            CaF = ValeurCelsius*1.8000 + 32

            résultatTextC = (EntréeCelsius, "devient", CaF, "°C")
            RésultatCaF = Label(window, text=résultatTextC, font=("Segoe print", 20), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
            RésultatCaF.place(x=100, y=300)
    else:
        print("ERREUR")
        
titreApp = Label(window, text="Convertisseur de degrés", font=("Segoe print", 20), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
titreApp.pack(pady=40)

titreEntréeTypeConversion = Label(window, text="De Farenheit à Celsius, ou l'inverse (A ou B) : ", font=("Segoe print", 15), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
titreEntréeTypeConversion.place(x=20, y=130)

EntréeConversion = Entry(window, width=15)
EntréeConversion.place(x=490, y=143)

if __name__=='__main__':
    window.bind("<Return>", choixUser)
    window.mainloop()
```

Oh, and to tell more, there's no error in the shell when I run the script, so I am really stuck :(

Comment: You're creating an Entry for the user to type a number into - `EntréeFarenheit`, for example - and then *immediately* calling `.get()` on it.  The result is an empty string, of course - you haven't given the user any chance to type anything!  You need to do the `.get()` and the conversion *later* - perhaps in response to a button click.

Comment: GUIs doesn't work like `input()` in text mode. It doesn't create widget at once and it doesn't wait for user data but it only informs what to display in window when it will run `mainloop()`. You could create `Button` and assign function with calculation and it will run your calculation when you put value and press button.

Comment: btw: When you run function then many GUIs doesn't add new widgets but they wait for end of your widgets and they redraw all widgets in one moment. Your `choixUser` should only create Entry field and use `bind` to assign another function which will calculate changes. `EntréeFarenheit.bind('<Return>', calculate_celsius)`

Comment: btw: there is good rule to use `english` names for variables and functions, and use `lower_case_names` for variables and functions. And `import *` is not preferred. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

Many `GUIs` don't work like `input()` in text mode. Widgets don't wait for user data but they only inform `mainloop` what it has to display after running function. And `mainloop` add new widgets (or redraw old widgets) after running `choixUser` so you try to `get()` values before user can see widgets and put value.

You need `Button` which will run code when user put data in `Entry`, or you have to `bind` function to widget and it will execute it later.

---

Full working code.

There is document [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which suggest to use English names and use `lower_case_names` for functions and variables.

I use the same names for widgets so later it can be simpler to remove them before next calculations (but I didn't add this part of code)

```
import tkinter as tk  # PE8: `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter.messagebox as msg

# --- classes ---  # PEP8: `CamemCaseNames`

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names`

def calculate_celsius(event):

    #input_value = input_value_entry.get()
    input_value = event.widget.get()
    
    if len(input_value) > 0:
        try:
            input_value = int(input_value)
        except ValueError:
            msg.showwarning("Error", "Need Integer Value")
        else:
            output_value = (input_value - 32)/1.8000

            output_text = (input_value, "devient", output_value, "°C")
            output_value_label = tk.Label(window, text=output_text, font=("Segoe print", 20), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
            output_value_label.place(x=200, y=300)
    else:
        msg.showwarning("Error", "Too Short")

def calculate_farenheit(event):

    #input_value = input_value_entry.get()
    input_value = event.widget.get()
    
    if len(input_value) > 0:
        try:
            input_value = int(input_value)
        except ValueError:
            msg.showwarning("Error", "Need Integer Value")
        else:
            output_value = (input_value * 1.8000) - 32

            output_text = (input_value, "devient", output_value, "°F")
            output_value_label = tk.Label(window, text=output_text, font=("Segoe print", 20), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
            
            output_value_label.place(x=200, y=300)
    else:
        msg.showwarning("Error", "Too Short")
        
def user_choise(event):  # PEP8: `english` names for functions
    #global input_value_entry  # inform Python to assign to global variable because I need it in other functions
    
    #selected = select_entry.get()
    selected = event.widget.get()
    
    selected = selected.upper()
    
    if selected == "A":
        input_value_label = tk.Label(window, text="Degrés Farenheit : ", font=("Segoe print", 15), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
        input_value_label.place(x=20, y=230)
        
        input_value_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=15)
        input_value_entry.place(x=220, y=243)
       
        input_value_entry.bind('<Return>', calculate_celsius)

    elif selected == "B":
        input_value_label = tk.Label(window, text="Degrés Celsius : ", font=("Segoe print", 15), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
        input_value_label.place(x=20, y=230)
        
        input_value_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=15)
        input_value_entry.place(x=185, y=243)

        input_value_entry.bind('<Return>', calculate_farenheit)
    else:
        msg.showwarning("Error", "Wrong selection")

# --- main ---

if __name__== '__main__':

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Conversion")
    window.geometry("720x480")
    window.configure(bg="turquoise")
            
    titre_app = tk.Label(window, text="Convertisseur de degrés", font=("Segoe print", 20), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
    titre_app.pack(pady=40)

    select_label = tk.Label(window, text="De Farenheit à Celsius, ou l'inverse (A ou B) : ", font=("Segoe print", 15), bg="turquoise", fg="white")
    select_label.place(x=20, y=130)

    select_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=15)
    select_entry.place(x=490, y=143)

    #window.bind("<Return>", user_choice)
    select_entry.bind("<Return>", user_choise)

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi @furas, could you please check your email?

Comment: Thanks a lot furas, now I understand my error.